# Xcode No such module when importing parent xcframework

Tags: ios, xcframework

I'm trying to import and use an xcframework which has a child xcframework inside and I'm getting a `no such module X` on the child framework when I try to import the parent.

The specific error is `arm64-apple-ios.private` No such module `X` which repeats itself twice. I have set the framework search paths inside the parent framework to `$(SRCROOT) recursive` and the architectures are set to standard. The framework build script merges the two archives (Simulator & iOS) which contains the child framework in the right location.

Build script:

```
xcodebuild archive \
    -project NAME.xcodeproj \
    -scheme NAME \
    -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
    -archivePath "build/SIMULATOR.xcarchive" \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \

xcodebuild archive \
    -project NAME.xcodeproj \
    -scheme NAME \
    -destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
    -archivePath "build/IOS.xcarchive" \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \


xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
    -framework "build/SIMULATOR.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/NAME.framework" \
    -framework "build/IOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/NAME.framework" \
    -output "build/universal/NAME.xcframework"
```

Can't see a solution to the error elsewhere so is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

I've never gotten child xcframeworks to embed successfully into a parent as a single, standalone import.  I've had some success building an xcframework that has a child dependency that IS packaged WITH the child dependency.  Both xcframeworks (the parent and the child) have to be linked to the consuming target.